# Graphite does not show all the data points

Tags: monitoring, graphite

My program is sending data item every second but when I refresh my graphite graph, I only see few of them. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Start with checking /opt/graphite/conf/storage-schemas.conf to see what is default data precision. From there you can either modify default or add your own regex to match your meta data to store at higher precision

More information:
http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config-carbon.html#storage-schemas-conf